# VBA Looping through range and deleting rows based on value

Tags: vba, loops, row, rows

I'm not sure why but i'm having a lot of difficulty running this code to loop through the range and delete the rows based on the value.  This code is part of a bigger macro i'm writing but it all runs well up to this point.

```
Dim Lastrowresults as integer
Dim Counter as integer
Dim Resultsheet as worksheet
Dim rowcounter as integer

Set resultsheet=sheets("Search Results")
LastRowResults = ResultSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    For Counter = 3 To LastRowResults
      If ResultSheet.Range("I" & Counter).Value = "No" Then
         RowCounter = ResultSheet.Range("I" & Counter).Row
         Rows(RowCounter).EntireRow.Delete
     End If
    Next Counter
```

Comment: What is the problem?  What is the expected behavior? What is the undesired behavior?

Comment: I'm expecting the rows to be deleted when the macro is finished running but they aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it was deleting rows but that would move the row up to #3 again, so then it would essentially skip that row by moving to row #4..  this is the workaround i figured out

```
    If SgLendsQ.Value = True Then
        LastRowResults = ResultSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        DelC = 3
        For Counter = 3 To LastRowResults
            If ResultSheet.Range("I" & DelC).Value = "No" Then
                ResultSheet.Rows(DelC).EntireRow.Delete
            ElseIf ResultSheet.Range("I" & DelC).Value = "Yes" Then
                DelC = DelC + 1
            End If
        Next Counter
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your bigger macro have screen updating off before the row deletion?

Maybe you can try this line before you delete the rows: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

And turn it on at the end: `Application.ScreenUpdating = true`

Comment: Yeah i have screen updating turned off, then turned back on at the end

Comment: ha sorry my mistake I thought your macro was slow to run. Maybe it is because it is not deleting the rows in the correct sheet? `ResultSheet.Rows(RowCounter).EntireRow.Delete`